# How can I create a single Clojure source file which can be safely used as a script and a library without AOT compilation?

Tags: scripting, clojure

I’ve spent some time researching this and though I’ve found some relevant info,

Here’s what I’ve found:

- [SO question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973106/what-is-the-clojure-equivalent-of-the-python-idiom-if-name-main) “What is the clojure equivalent of the Python idiom `if __name__ == '__main__'`?”
- [Some techniques at RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Scripted_Main#Clojure)
- [A few discussions in the Cojure Google Group](https://groups.google.com/group/clojure/search?group=clojure&q=script+main&qt_g=Search+this+group) — most from 2009

but none of them have answered the question satisfactorily.

My Clojure source code file defines a namespace and a bunch of functions. There’s also a function which I want to be invoked when the source file is run as a script, but *never* when it’s imported as a library.

So: now that it’s 2012, is there a way to do this yet, without AOT compilation? If so, please enlighten me!

Comment: The answer might depend on what precisely you mean by "run as a script".

Comment: I mean run from bash, as in `clj /path/to/myscript.clj` or by putting  a hashbang at the top of the file and making it executable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming by *run as a script* you mean via clojure.main as follows:

```
java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main /path/to/myscript.clj
```

If so then there is a simple technique: put all the library functions in a separate namespace like `mylibrary.clj`. Then myscript.clj can use/require this library, as can your other code. But the specific functions in myscript.clj will only get called when it is run as a script.

As a bonus, this also gives you a good project structure, as you don't want script-specific code mixed in with your general library functions.

**EDIT:**

I don't think there is a robust within Clojure itself way to determine whether a single file was launched as a script or loaded as a library - from Clojure's perspective, there is *no difference* between the two (it all gets loaded in the same way via [Compiler](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java).load(...) in the Clojure source for anyone interested).

Options if you really want to detect the manner of the launch:

- Write a main class in Java which sets a static flag then launched the Clojure script. You can easily test this flag from Clojure.
- Use AOT compilation to implement a Clojure main class which sets a flag
- Use [*command-line-args*](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/*command-line-args*) to indicate script usage. You'll need to pass an extra parameter like "script" on the command line.
- Use a platform-specific method to determine the command line (e.g. from the environment variables in Windows)
- Use the --eval option in the [clojure.main command line](http://clojure.org/repl_and_main) to load your clj file and launch a specific function that represents your script. This function can then set a script-specific flag if needed
- Use one of the [methods for detecting the Java main class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939932/how-to-determine-main-class-at-runtime-in-threaded-java-application)

Comment: I know I can do this, but my question is whether a single Clojure file can safely be used as both a script and a library. I don’t believe you’ve answered the question.

Comment: @Avi - OK I've updated the answer. You can safely do it, but detecting the difference between the two might be tricky (as far as I can work out, Clojure regards them as the same thing....)

Comment: thanks! check out my answer below to see an approach I came up with in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve come up with an approach which, while deeply flawed, seems to work.

I identify which namespaces are known when my program is running as a script. Then I can compare that number to the number of namespaces known at runtime. The idea is that if the file is being used as a lib, there should be at least one more namespace present than in the script case.

Of course, this is extremely hacky and brittle, but it does seem to work:

```
(defn running-as-script
    "This is hacky and brittle but it seems to work. I’d love a better
    way to do this; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/9027265"
    []
    (let
        [known-namespaces
            #{"clojure.set"
                "user"
                "clojure.main" 
                "clj-time.format" 
                "clojure.core" 
                "rollup" 
                "clj-time.core" 
                "clojure.java.io" 
                "clojure.string" 
                "clojure.core.protocols"}]
        (= (count (all-ns)) (count known-namespaces))))
```

Comment: clever, but very likely to break!

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful: the github project [lein-oneoff](https://github.com/mtyaka/lein-oneoff) describes itself as "dependency management for one-off, single-file clojure programs."

This lets you define everything in one file, but you do need the `oneoff` plugin installed in order to run it from the command line.